# Source command still looking for bashrc file in the wrong folder

Tags: bashrc, source

I am new to ubuntu and basically know nothing. I am using ubuntu 12.04 (need this exact version). I was trying to install OpenFOAM 2.1.1, from the source code. I needed to source the bashrc file, I did exactly as explained on their website (http://openfoam.org/download/2-1-1-source/) but it did not work. I needed OpenFOAM urgently, so I downloaded normally rather than from the source code. When you install that way, OpenFOAM is created in /opt instead of home. OpenFOAM was working, but the solver I was gonna use was not, so I removed OpenFOAM completely. Now I'm trying to install from the source code again, and in source bashrc step, I keep getting this error:

```
bash: /opt/openfoam211/etc/bashrc: No such file or directory
```

Why is it still trying to source to the old file that does not even exist anymore? The annoying thing is, I did it before, exact same computer, exact same steps, but I reinstalled ubuntu a while back (same exact ubuntu) and this time I can't do it.

Edit: Apparently I thought bashrc and .bashrc is the same thing, and they were obviously not. Problem solved.

Comment: Did you edit your `~/.bashrc` file to include `source $HOME/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.1.1/etc/bashrc`, and then do a `source $HOME/.bashrc` at the `terminal` command prompt?

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that.

Comment: In `terminal`, what is the output of `cat $HOME/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.1.1/etc/bashrc`? And `grep -i openfoam $HOME/.bashrc`?

Comment: First one gives this as result http://www.pasted.co/a0d4c73f and second one this `source /opt/openfoam211/etc/bashrc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

When editing your ~/.bashrc file, the instructions say to add the following command...

```
source $HOME/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.1.1/etc/bashrc
```

and you entered...

```
source /opt/openfoam211/etc/bashrc
```

You could actually even leave the edit out of ~/.bashrc, because the file at `$HOME/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.1.1/etc/bashrc` is effectively empty.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation taking place here and all other comments have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51806/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-source-command-still-looking-for-bashrc-file-in).